# Can app.filter be called after app.controller?

Tags: angularjs

In this [Angular JS Pagination Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gr2uksvu/7/)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.filter('offset', function() {
alert('filter is called');
return function(input, start) {
    return input.slice(start);
};})

app.controller('someController', function($scope) {
alert('controller is called');
$scope.countries = [];
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.itemsPerPage = 20;
$scope.maxSize = 20;
$scope.totalItems = 250;

for(var i = 0; i < $scope.totalItems; i++){
    $scope.countries[i] = { name: 'country ' + i }
}
});
```

Is it possible to make for app.filter to be called before app.controller gets called? If yes, how can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

first off, your tag is not correct.  You might be including Angular UI Bootstrap as module dependency, but this is purely an Angular question, so you might want to fix that.

Second, filters are utility functions that operate on some piece(es) of data.  They are executed when you apply them.  There are several ways to apply them:

1. In HTML:  `<div ng-repeat="item in items | myFilter>`, or
2. In code:  `$filter('myFilter')(arguments_to_the_filter);` - note that you will need to inject the $filter service for this option.

If you are trying to filter your collection before the controller executes, if this is a route, you can add a `resolve` function that injects the filtered value, or, you can apply the filter first thing in the controller.

The correct workflow depends on your application, but typically, you inject your dependencies into your controller and you don't rely on loading the data in your controller.

Comment: I really appreciate your solution. I understood every thing until the "resolve" part. I'm very new to Angular Js. How could I apply the filter in the controller?

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider for more information on `resolve` functions.  To do it in your controller, you want to use option #2 above.  You will need to inject the `$filter` service into your controller in order to use this.